# Flutter Staggered view

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I want to e able to show a grid of search item, the width of the container should be dynamic based on the length of the text.

[image]

I tried using a staggered view, but this was the result [image]

```
 Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: MasonryGridView.count(
              itemCount: searchTerms.length,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 4,
              crossAxisSpacing: 4,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 12, vertical: 20),
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    searchTerms[index],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: pColor2,
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontFamily: 'Inter',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      height: 0,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

This is the list I am using